# Is there a way to declare a controller in AngularJS and only specify its dependencies once?

Tags: angularjs

In order to keep dependency injection working after minification I'm using this style to declare a controller:

```
myModule.controller('myController', ['$rootScope', 'Service', 
  function($rootScope, Service) {
    $scope.foo = 'bar';
}]);
```

Let's say you want to add another service. You'd have to add it in 2 places, in the array preceding the controller function, and as a parameter of the controller function itself. My question is, is there a way to make this DRY-er? Could you declare a dependency array and use that to build the outer array and the inner parameters, something like this?:

```
var dependencies = ['$rootScope', 'Service'];

var myProtoController = function() {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
};

var myController = dependencies.push(myProtoController.bind.apply(this, [this].concat(dependencies)));

myModule.controller('myController', myController);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use [Ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) in your tool chain?  It will convert your angular functions into the minify-able style you're currently using.

It integrates with grunt and rails, so it should be simple to use in your current pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Using `concat` ?

```
var deps = ['$rootScope', 'Service'];

myModule.controller('myCtrl', deps.concat(function ($scope, $rs, S) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
}));
```

Comment: I like it.  But there is a syntax error.  Your missing a closing paren.

Comment: It looks like you still need to write the dependencies twice in this one.

Comment: How so? But +1 for ngmin anyway, I just usually try to suggest from scratch-working solutions.